# Should I flag, edit or just downvote this obviously wrong answer?

Tags: discussion, flags, answers, low-quality-posts

As part of a question review, I stumbled upon [this poor answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18368676/806549):

> you are not doing anything wrong. the code you used is correct i have also used the same and i tried too and it is working on my side i do not know what is happening on your side. do check the other problems may be incorrectly done in your function.

My first reaction would be to flag it, probably as very low quality. But since we should not flag answers for being incorrect, I considered editing it instead. In the end, I downvoted and commented as I think the answer might be looking at the syntax as being correct instead of looking at the question as a whole.

What would be the proper cause of action?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer doesn't really contribute anything to the post.  It doesn't help the OP, and it certainly wouldn't help future readers.  Further, it is unclear whether editing it would make it any better.

A "Very Low Quality" flag would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

"Obviously wrong" should be downvoted and commented. But in this case it's not really wrong, it's simply not an answer / low quality. Do your best to see thin line between the 2.